# auto-update status field in table by checking current date and time in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two fields "status" and "datetime" in table. Status can be "pending", "due", "completed", "missed". How can I implement a background job which will auto-update the status field by checking the current date and time. Any suggestion how I can do it in Rails 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a cron job which will execute after some time .
You can use https://github.com/javan/whenever for it.

Create a rake task for your job.
Call the rake task from schedule.rb
In the rake write the code which will check if current date is "some condition", then update status = your status
Save
You can use sidekiq(https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) for background processing.

There is one alternative solution for the same problem:

Use the gem 'aasm' .Read the documentation from https://github.com/aasm/aasm
I hope this will help you.

Comment: The alternative solution - the state machine - is much safer.  Running a background job poses the risk that the actual status, as computed on-the-fly, will be different from whatever value is in the 'status' field in the DB.